# 3D Modeling Software for Programmer

Tags: unity, models, blender

I've recently learned how to make games for Unity3d, and now I want to start making games! I can't wait to start!

However, before I can make 3D games, I need to learn 3D modeling for character design, level design, and some animation.

What is the easiest 3D modeling software, compatible with Unity3d?   I do not want to spend too much time learning the software.  From what I've heard, Blender is a bit complicated to use. Maya and 3dsMax seem very powerful.

Could someone point me in the right direction?  I don't want to spend a lot of time learning.  I know its not that easy, but you guys have experience, you guys probably know out of all which one is easier and powerful.  Could you recommend a software?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I know programmers who love Max and think it's super easy and I know programmers who love Blender and its UI.  Whichever you learn first will be your favorite.

Comment: Pathachiever11, welcome to GDSE! I'm glad you're excited to get into game development, it really is great. However, your question is not on topic for this Q/A site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask. Specifically, this question is a "which technology to use" type question, and not a fit for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no single "best" 3D Modelling software.
But being a hobbyist, and a complete newbie: I'd go with **Blender**

You have tons of resources, and it's completely **free**, in both senses.
It's also multiplatform, so you can easily use it if you use GNU/Linux or Mac OS X.

It has it's own 3D game engine, and you can script it with Python, it's probably the best option for a programmer.

PS: And no, it's not that complicated ;)

Comment: Upvote for the Python interface. **As a programmer**, you can easily use Blender to script out your own import/export scripts, write your own procedural model scripts in Python, etc. using a more general-purpose language than MAXScript or MEL.

Answer (score 1):

I like 3DS Max, but when I have to choose $4k versus free, I will use Blender.

Comment: I would go with free too, but I'm able to get 3ds max free academic license... =P